# Deny access to url/views to unauthorized users

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, access-control

Is there a way to deny certain users (for example, allow admin and deny normal users) to access to specific url/views?

I'm doing this:

```
<?php if($this->session->userdata('level')==='1'):?>
        <h1>Hi!!!!</h1>
        <p>You can access!!</p>
    <?php elseif($this->session->userdata('level')==='2'):?>
        <h1>Level 2, access denied</h1>
    <?php else:?>
        <h1>Level 3, access denied</h1>
    <?php endif;?>
```

But I prefer not allowing to load the page, for example, not allowing them to access this url: http://localhost/login/page/posts

Comment: check type in constructor and redirect on particular view if not having access then.

Answer (score 0):

you need to load different pages from your controller, depending on user's session level:

your example url breaks down to:

```
http://localhost/login/page/posts
                /controller/function/parameter
```

so in your controller Login.php:

```
function page($page){
  $data['msg']='you need to login to access this page';
  if($page=='posts' && $this->session->userdata('level')==='2'){
    $this->load->view('posts'); // loads posts.php
  }else{
    $this->load->view('login', $data);  // loads login.php, you can display $msg
  }
}
```